# Localization is not picked up

Tags: swift

I have ran into a minor problem, my macOS app [RsyncOSX](https://github.com/rsyncOSX/RsyncOSX), which is localized, does not pick up localization of rawvalue enums.. I have googled, but not found any solution for it.. Hardcoding the string literals works, utilizing rawvalue not...

Localization is done by exporting xliffs and translate. Utilizing enum.rawvalues is not included in xliff exports... I have also tried to set the string value like `case once = "Once"`, export does not include translating `"Once"`

```
switch schedule {
case Scheduletype.once.rawValue
   return NSLocalizedString(Scheduletype.once.rawValue, comment: "main")
case Scheduletype.daily.rawValue:
   return NSLocalizedString(Scheduletype.daily.rawValue, comment: "main")
case Scheduletype.weekly.rawValue:
   return NSLocalizedString(Scheduletype.weekly.rawValue, comment: "main")
case Scheduletype.manuel.rawValue:
   return NSLocalizedString(Scheduletype.manuel.rawValue, comment: "main")
default:
   return ""
}
```

```
enum Scheduletype: String {
   case once
   case daily
   ....
}
```

Comment: Add the values you've given in strings file.

Comment: If the enums and strings are equal, utilizing Swiftformat removes the string literals stating not required...  make sense...

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the switch statement works as expected? I'd rather do something like this:

```swift
if let scheduleType = Scheduletype(rawValue: schedule) {
    return NSLocalizedString(scheduleType.rawValue, comment: "main")
} else {
    return ""
}
```

Less code, less error prone, easier to debug.

**EDIT** 
Thinking of it, you can completely omit the enum:

```swift
return NSLocalizedString(schedule, comment: "main")
```

Comment: The switch works, in a localized version english translations are presented....I will try your suggestion later..

Comment: One part of the problem is that exporting xliff for translations does not include enum.rawvalues... So the suggested solution does not work..